# Multiple html pages with socket.io

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, sockets

I'm working with socket.io mysql and html on NodeJS. I want to login in another html page than my index.html (like login.html).

With a lot of searching I did this but when I click on the link the content is always that of index.html

app.js

```
const http = require('http');
const fs = require('fs');
const mysql = require('mysql');
const path = require('path');
const ext = /[\w\d_-]+\.[\w\d]+$/;
const con = mysql.createConnection({
  host: "localhost",
  user: "root",
  password: "",
  database: "database"
});

const server = http.createServer(function(req, res){
  if (req.url === '/') {
      res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
      fs.createReadStream('views/index.html').pipe(res);
  } else if (ext.test(req.url)) {
    console.log(req.url);
    fs.exists(path.join(__dirname, req.url), function (exists) {
      if (exists) {
        res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
        fs.createReadStream('views/index.html').pipe(res);
      } else {
        res.writeHead(404, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
        fs.createReadStream('views/404.html').pipe(res);
      }
    });
  }
});

const io = require('socket.io').listen(server);

io.sockets.on('connection', function(socket) {

});

server.listen(8080);
```

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>Test</title>
</head>

<body>
  <a href="views/login.html">Login</a>

  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
  <script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
  <script>
    var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:8080');
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Have a nice day,

Comment: If you use a logger, you can see the problem : See the one in the docs of express js (http://expressjs.com/fr/4x/api.html),  section : router.use([path], [function, ...] function) . A proper way to do app with socket/express could be like that : https://github.com/HenriqueLBorges/expressChat

Comment: There is no error.. Just the content doesn't change

Comment: You should normally use regex like express expects . This site offers a short tutorial + soms useful tools : https://www.kevinleary.net/regex-route-express/ .